# Difficulty populating a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I started programming a couple weeks ago for a personal project (MKUltra'd into learning to code by subliminal messages in American Political Campaign), so don't hesitate to tear into my dumb errors like a beast into tenderest young shoot.

I'm trying to populate a JComboBox from an ArrayList, I've already gone through a bunch of possible solutions and similar questions on here and arrived at a solution that seems like it should work - populating a model from the ArrayList and then instantiating the ComboBox with that model - but doesn't. Here's the snippet:

```
public class Window {   

    public Window() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);      
        frame.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ArrayList<String> yearList = new ArrayList<String>();
        yearList.add("2019");
        StackExchangeQ.setYears(yearList);
        StackExchangeQ fakePanel = new StackExchangeQ();        
        frame.add(fakePanel);       
        frame.pack();       
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
public class StackExchangeQ extends JPanel {
private static ArrayList<String> yearList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void setYears(ArrayList<String> userYears) {     
        for(int i = 0; i < userYears.size(); i++) {
            yearList.add(userYears.get(i));         
        }
    }

    public void StackExchangeQ() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));     
        this.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); 

        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> yearModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
        yearModel.addElement("All");
        for(int i = 1; i < yearList.size(); i++) {
            yearModel.addElement(yearList.get(i));
            System.out.println(yearModel.getElementAt(i));
        }
        JComboBox<String> yearSelect = new JComboBox<String>(yearModel);     
        menuPanel.add(yearSelect, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
}
```

Basically it should show a list of years that are taken from a textfield input and entered into the yearList ArrayList. I've checked the flow of information (?) up to the point of populating the model, it fails at the point I try to populate the combobox.

***OKAY in editing this to create a minimal reproducible example I found what seems to be the problem, because a week ago when I was REALLY just starting I couldn't get the ArrayList passed properly to the StackExchangeQ object for some reason and my hack was to make it a static field in the latter and call the static method setYears() before creating the instance, as you can see in the above example lmao. making the ArrayList a non-static field and passing it properly seems to make the ComboBox work somehow (but it's still a black box to me).

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *it fails at the point I try to populate the combobox* - I have no idea what "fail" means to you. 1) Do you see values from your System.out.println(...)? 2) you are using a FlowLayout, but you try to use a BorderLayout.PAGE_START constraint. You can't use a constraint from a specific layout manager in another layout manager. 3) When you add components to a visible GUI your need to revalidate() the panel you add the components to. 4) the code you posted here only show how to add the combo box to the panel, You don't show where the panel is added to the frame. Post a [mre]

Comment: Sorry, by "fail" I meant that I can see the values using System.out.println up to the model, but the combobox remains empty. I don't seem to be having any problems with my layout - the "StackExchangeQ" panel is added to the frame in the class from which the "StackExchangeQ" is called, and I'm adding the "menuPanel" JPanel w/ a FlowLayout, to the PAGE_START of "StackExchangeQ" (extends JPanel) so that I can put multiple components in this area. Don't think that's an error, but thank you for the tip on revalidate() & I'll edit it so it's a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `public void StackExchangeQ()`. Shouldn't be `public StackExchangeQ()` **(a constructor)** in order to have the panel initiated when the object is created? Otherwise you would have to:

```
StackExchangeQ fakePanel = new StackExchangeQ();
fakePanel.StackExchangeQ();
frame.add(fakePanel);
```

Also, you do not need to have `yearList` declared as `static`. Actually you do not even have to have `yearList`. Just declare the model of the combo box as a field and populate Strings right to the model.

Here is what i mean:

```
public class Window {
    public static class StackExchangeQ extends JPanel {
        private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> yearModel;

        public void setYears(ArrayList<String> userYears) {
            yearModel.removeAllElements();
            userYears.forEach(yearModel::addElement);
        }

        public StackExchangeQ() {
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            this.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            yearModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
            JComboBox<String> yearSelect = new JComboBox<String>(yearModel);
            menuPanel.add(yearSelect, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        }
    }

    public Window() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ArrayList<String> yearList = new ArrayList<String>();
        yearList.add("All");
        yearList.add("2019");
        StackExchangeQ fakePanel = new StackExchangeQ();
        fakePanel.setYears(yearList);
        frame.add(fakePanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Window());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was indeed the lack of constructor and the resulting misuse of ```Static```. As for the ```ArrayList```, I'm getting the values from a JTextField and it was a bit too complicated for me to include it here in minimized form. Thanks for your time!

Comment: just curious, what is the reason for adding the ```DefaultComboBoxModel``` as a field?

Comment: @mudeffigy Without the model as a field, i would not be able to access it inside `setYears` method and populate the data. (Actually, i would, but in a silly non-required way).